# Throwing error when deleting last node in linked list c++

Tags: c++

I am writing some code to delete the last node in the linked list, it is
working but throwing this error when printing the list back out.

```
void deleteRecords(Student* head) {
  Student* current = head;
  while (input != 2) {
    cout << "Do you want to delete records? 1 = yes, 2 = nein: " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    if (input == 1) {
      Student* current = head;

      if (head->next) {
        current = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = current;
      }
    }
  }
  printDetails(head);
}
```

Print details:

```
void printDetails(Student* head) {
  struct Student* current = head;  // Current holds the current item in the list
                                   // (holds name, stock etc...)
  if (head == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  while (current != NULL)  // While not at end of the list...
  {
    double total = 0;
    cout << current->id << "    " << current->firstName << "    "
         << current->lastName << " " << current->course << " " << current->yos
         << endl;  // Output
    current = current->next;  // Point to the next item in link list...
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Error it is printing:

[image]

Comment: [`0xFEEEFEEE` is a magic pattern](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) that the VC debug runtime uses to overwrite freed memory. From your error message you probably do something equivalent to `*(deleted_ptr - 0x0c)` in some place. Be sure to memorize the magic patterns used by the debug runtime, they can be really helpful in hunting down errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you delete a pointer, make the pointer as NULL, for example,

```
delete head;
head = (Student *)NULL;
```

Also, at the very beginning, check if head != NULL before accessing head->next

Comment: The error is still there, maybe because I am setting everything to null?

Comment: Also try to apply C++11, i.e. head = nullptr;

Answer (score 0):

If `head` is `NULL`, `head->next` is meaningless and gives the access violation error. Try to break out from the loop once `head` is `NULL`.

```
while (input!=2)
{
    if (head==NULL)
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You never change the contents of any nodes, and you never change the value of any pointers.

That means that whatever value used to be in the `next` member would normally still be lying around in memory after the nodes have been destroyed.

Luckily, your debug build is setting the contents of freed memory to a value that will cause an error when you try to access it.

The first thing you should do is take out pencil and paper and figure out what you need to do to delete a node.
There's no better way to debug pointer algorithms than by drawing boxes and arrows by hand.